# How do I send a list of MDX parameters to SSRS via ParameterValue in VB?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, mdx

How do I send a list of MDX parameters to SSRS via ParameterValue in VB?
I’m not sure if that is the correct question, but here are the symptoms: When I send one store ID to SSRS I get back valid data.   But as soon as I string together a series of stores IDs it returns – (dashes) where numeric values should be.
So this returns valid sales numbers:

```
Private parametersRdl(1) As ParameterValue

        parametersRdl(0) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(0).Name = "StoreLocations"
        parametersRdl(0).Value = "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[456789]”

        parametersRdl(1) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(1).Name = "EndDate"
        parametersRdl(1).Value = "[Current Date].[YearMonthDate].[Month].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]"
```

This returns dashes instead of sales numbers:

```
Private parametersRdl(1) As ParameterValue

        parametersRdl(0) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(0).Name = "StoreLocations"
        parametersRdl(0).Value = "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[456789], "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[123456]”

        parametersRdl(1) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(1).Name = "EndDate"
        parametersRdl(1).Value = "[Current Date].[YearMonthDate].[Month].&[2012-12-01T00:00:00]"
```

I have tried various parameter separators, such as &, comma, ‘\,’, etc.
Does ParameterValue accept a list? Do I set or append parametersRdl(0).Value  multiple times?
Of course when I set a default set in BIDS it works great. When I send a list via the web the logs show it appends them with \, (slash comma) but that doesn’t seem to work.

Visual Studio 2010, VB.net, SSRS 2010 (management), SSRS 2005 (execution)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here’s the answer.  You can add multiple values for the same parameter as long as you reference the parameter by name.  There are a few ways to do this.
The first method allows you to define the exact amount of list objects, however the second method makes it much easier to add a bunch of values.  Regardless, each method allows you to add a list of MDX values to the same SSRS parameter.

Method 1: Add values by specific index.

```
Private parametersRdl(7) As ParameterValue
‘ Add your other parameters 
        parametersRdl(5) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(5).Name = "StoresStoreLocation"
        parametersRdl(5).Value = "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[123]"

        parametersRdl(6) = New ParameterValue()
        parametersRdl(6).Name = "StoresStoreLocation"
        parametersRdl(6).Value = "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[456]"
```

Method 2: Split a string value into a list and loop through it.

```
Private parametersRdl(50) As ParameterValue


        Dim StoresString As String = "123, 456, 789, 741, 852, 963"
        Dim StoresList() As String = StoresString.Split(",")

        For n As Integer = 0 To StoresList.Count - 1
            parametersRdl(n) = New ParameterValue()
            parametersRdl(n).Name = "StoresStoreLocation"
            parametersRdl(n).Value = "[Stores].[Store Location].[Stores].&[" + StoresList(n) + "]"
        Next
```

P.S. As usual it took many hours of banging my head against my desk to figure this out.  I hope it helps.